# How do I set the number of "webcontainer worker-threads" in jboss as 7?

Tags: performance, configuration, jboss, jboss7.x

Most app. servers provide a way of tuning the number of WebContainer worker-threads when it goes down to tuning. Is it possible to do that in JBoss AS 7.x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can tune the HTTP Conector of the AS7 web subsystem. The available attributes you can tune for the HTTP Connector are described here [The Http Connector](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/http.html). To define the max-connections for this connector you need change it in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml or $JBOSS_HOME/domain/configuration/domain.xml

See this piece of configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
   <connector name="http" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
        scheme="http" 
        socket-binding="http"
        max-connections="250"/>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

To define a thread pool specific for the HTTP Connector you need to use the AS7 threads subsystem like this one:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.0">
  <bounded-queue-thread-pool name="http-executor" blocking="true">
    <core-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
    <queue-length count="10" per-cpu="20" />
    <max-threads count="10" per-cpu="20" />
    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds" />
  </bounded-queue-thread-pool>
</subsystem>
```

and then you need to reference it in the executor attribute of the HTTP Connector. See this piece of config:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
   <connector name="http" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
        scheme="http" 
        socket-binding="http"
        max-connections="250"
        executor="http-executor"/>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

For more details about tuning the AS7 see this post [JBoss AS 7 Performance tuning - Tuning Web server thread pool](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-performance/jboss-as-7-performance-tuning/page-4) on the masterjboss.com.

Comment: I run some tests and find out that actually you can set some parameters  but there's some self tuning adjustment that aparently automatically changes the settings for some minimal configuration. (In my case I have set core and max threads to 20 but it got automatically adjusted to 34 in a 8 core processors O.S)